# How to add custom footer to an SSIS flat file - seperate component or script task?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a data flow component, comprise of the following :

1.) Read Excel file
2.) "Script transformation component"
3.) Write to a flat file

Everything works fine, however I was trying to add header & footer.
 **Both header & footer are custom and have to be derived from the data in the file.**

I can open the file in C# and write the low level code, but this seems to be a pretty common task & I thought there would be something generic.

Let me know if someone has done this.

Comment: Found this, seems to be the correct approach, would like to confirm - http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/sql-server-l/ssis-adding-a-header-and-a-footer-to-a-flat-file-destination-2442798

Comment: Out of curiosity, what data in the file needs to be added to to the header/footer? Things like checksums, total amounts etc?

Comment: yes, summarizing data and putting data by reading from another connection manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach listed in the Toolbox.com article will certainly work. (You'll need to add another data flow, but data flows are cheap.)

On the other hand, since you've already got a Script Component in your existing data flow, you can use that to generate the header and trailer rows.

First, change the SynchronousInputID of the Script Component output to `None` so that you can generate additional rows:

[image]

Next, update the ProcessInputRow() method and add a FinishOutputs() method along these lines:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private bool _headerWritten = false;

    public override void IncomingRows_ProcessInputRow(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
    {
        if (!_headerWritten)
        {
            // Code to write the header row goes here
            _headerWritten = true;
        }
        OutgoingRowsBuffer.AddRow();
        // do whatever other processing you need for this row of input
    }

    public override void FinishOutputs()
    {
        base.FinishOutputs();
        // Code to write the footer row goes here
    }
}
```

This approach requires a bit more code but lets you do everything in one pass, which for sufficiently huge files may be important. (On the other hand, an Excel spreadsheet shouldn't be **that** big ...)

Comment: Thanks Edmund. Let me check that ! Also did you mean - "but data flows are NOT cheap" ?

Comment: My comment "but data flows are cheap" was actually serious - assuming, of course, that the input file isn't huge. I don't have a good rule of thumb for how big the file has to be before it's a problem because it depends on other things as well, but it is something I keep in mind when I find myself tasked with speeding up a slow process. Meanwhile, glad to help!